# Embedded editable Google sheets witout colum letters and row numbers

Tags: html, google-sheets

I have this editable google sheet embed code that is working great but is there anyone that knows a way to hide the colum letters and the row numbers? Ideally also the tab name and the bottom ribbon as well?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700px" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SpreadsheetID/edit?chrome=false&amp;widget=false&amp;single=true&amp;rm=minimal#gid=0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can specify the range you would like to publish by adding the url parameter `range`:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="700px" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&range=C1:F100">
</iframe>
```

If the range you would like to publish is not adjacent, consider creating an additional sheets in your spreadsheet that you populate with [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en9) only with the columns you would like to display and then publish only this sheet:

[image]

Comment: I think OP is expecting users to be able to edit the sheet. This way, users won't be able to do that.

Comment: I see. In this case it might make sense to create a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) where the UI is populated with data from columns of interest in the spreadsheet and user edits are written back to the spreasheet on button press.

Comment: Thanks @Alfredo, yes that is what I was looking for.

Comment: In this case I would not know of another way, apart from what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Is is something that would be interesting for you?

Comment: Yes that would be great but I think it is a bit over my abilities at the moment